# Onclick method using JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found an `onclick` example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762297/display-menu-in-another-div-using-javascript-error). I did everything given on the page and I don't know what's wrong/going on.

I did what's given there and when I create a new page, it's not working. What's going wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/u2kxu2hz/4)

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftmenu">
  <ul id="leftmenuidfrmslt" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <a href="" onclick="mob();"><li><span class="flaticon-smart">
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function mob() {
    hidemenus();
    document.getElementById('mobi').style.display = "block";
}

function hidemenus() {
    document.getElementById('mobi').style.display = "none";
 }
```

Onclick display menu

```
 <div id="mobi" style="display:none;z-index:99;" class="answer_list" >
   <p class="flaticon-right127"><a href="#">Mobile&nbsp;Phones</a>
   <p class="flaticon-right127"><a href="#">Tablets</a></p>
   <p class="flaticon-right127"><a href="#">Mobile&nbsp;Accessories</a></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: my full code http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/u2kxu2hz/4/

Comment: You have a syntax error.  At first glance, you never close the `hidemenus` function.

Comment: For starters, the `hidemenus` function is not closed with `}`. Please check you're console for error reports.. (In chrome: right-click > inspect element > console-tab in bottom window). Also, you `hidemenus` and directly show them (2nd line) after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a quick glance through your code, you are trying to find an element by ID 'mobi' but there is no element that has that ID in the jsfiddle you provided.

So the function doesn't do anything because it can't find the element which it can apply the change/action to.

I tried a few other ids: 'elec', 'vehi' and couldn't find elements with those IDs either.

Comment: Example from W3: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_getelementbyid

Comment: check my fiddle i have added still not working http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/u2kxu2hz/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set id attribute of the links.

For example:

```
<a href="" onclick="mob();">
```

Add this line its id:

```
<a id="mobi" href="" onclick="mob();">
```

Comment: still negative result

Comment: <a id="mobi" href="" onclick="mob(); return false;">

Comment: `id="mobi"` is the _target div_ not the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to make it more simple:

```
var allIds = ['mobi','elec','vehi','home','pets','book','clot','kids','spor','serv','jobs','real'];

function hideAll() {
    for( id in allIds ) {
         document.getElementById( id ).style.display = "none";
    }
}

function showMenu( idToShow ) {
    hideAll();
    document.getElementById( idToShow ).style.display = "block";
}
```

In you're HTML you can now:

```
<a href="" onclick="showMenu('elec');"></a>
```

Also, as Code Whisperer pointed out, the elements you want to show should have ids:

```
<div id="elec"></div>
```

Comment: i get result before clicking